# How to add a constant value to all the values in a dictionary after merging two dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

i need to add two dictionaries and add a constant value to all the values in the dictionary and the code is:

```
def Merge(dict1, dict2): 
    res = {**dict1, **dict2} 
    return res 

box1= {'box1x1': 277, 'box1y1': 596}
box2= {'box1x2': 73, 'boxy2': 19}
box3= Merge(box1,box2)
print(box3)
```

Result:

```
 {'box1x1': 277, 'box1y1': 596, 'box1x2': 73, 'boxy2': 19}
```

Now i need to add value 40 to all the values in the dictionary. how can I?

Comment: new_d = {k:v+40 for k,v in d.items()}

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. _Now i need to add value 40 to all the values in the dictionary. how can I?_ What have you tried? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using dict comprehension,

```
>>> d = {'box1x1': 277, 'box1y1': 596, 'box1x2': 73, 'boxy2': 19}
>>> some_constant = 40
>>> {k:v+some_constant for k,v in d.items()}
{'box1x1': 317, 'box1y1': 636, 'box1x2': 113, 'boxy2': 59}
```